# Passing a message to the front end

Tags: php, static-variables, custom-errors

I am kind of experimenting with files in PHP and such, and I wrote this basic class, which isn't fully implemented, as you can see:

```
class AisisCore_FileHandling_Upload_Upload{

    private $_file;

    static private $_errors;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->init();
    }

    public function init(){}

    public function check_file(array $file, string $size){
        $this->_file = $file;

        if ($this->_file['size'] > $size) {
            $this->_error('size', 'The size of your zip exceeds that of the set size: ' . $size);
        }

        if ($this->_file['type'] != 'application/zip') {
            $this->_error('type', 'File type must be a .zip');
        }

        if (!strops($this->_file['name'], 'package') || !strops($this->_file['name'] == 'theme')) {
            $this->_error('name', 'File uploaded does not contain the words "package" or "theme." Unreconized.');
        }elseif(strops($this->_file['name'], 'package')){
            $this->package($this->_file);
        }elseif(strops($this->_file['name'], 'theme')){
            $this->theme($this->_file);
        }   

        wp_safe_redirect(admin_url('admin.php?page=aisis-core-upload'));
    }

    public function theme(array $file){ 
    }

    public function package(array $file){
    }

    protected function _error(string $code, string $message){
        self::$_errors[$code] = $message;
    }

    public function get_all_errors(){
        foreach($this->_errors as $code=>$message){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-error"><strong>'.$code.'</strong>: '.$message.'</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

This class interacts with a form:

```
$upload = new AisisCore_FileHandling_Upload_Upload();

if($_POST['aisis_upload']){
    $upload->check_file($_FILES['aisis_file'], $_POST['MAX']);
}

$upload->get_all_errors();

<form action="" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="control-group">
            <input type="file" class="input-xlarge" name="aisis_file" placeholder="Your file.">
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX" value="1024">
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload Zip" name="aisis_upload">
        </div>
    </fieldset> 
</form>
```

When the form is submitted with a file that breaks the rules of the "check" it should (as you see from the `wp_safe_redirect(admin_url('admin.php?page=aisis-core-upload'));`) redirect back to the page it was on (this redirect also happens when all is said and done, weather the file passed or failed.

the problem I am getting is that I am storing errors in a static variable that should be saved when I return back to the page, from there I should be able to get the errors out,
instead what I get is nothing. just a blank page, no errors spit out, xdebug is silent...

how would I debug this? I tried var dumping the errors before and after submission but before its null, like it should be and after submission its....well the page is blank.

thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to go about debugging is to comment out the redirect, but you could use session variable to carry information to the next page if you wanted as well. That being said, if you're looking for errors check out your strpos(and its strpos not strops) usage.

```
(!strops($this->_file['name'], 'package') || !strops($this->_file['name'] == 'theme'))
```

in the first condition you should check against !==false(string contains needle) or === false(string does not contain needle). if the name is 'package' strpos will return 0 which == false, probably not what you were going for. and the second condition it seems strpos is just unnecessary or at least used wrong. for false values with strpos do it like this

```
if(strpos($this->_file['name'] , 'theme' ) === false)
```

for more info [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)